# For loop in python- to generate output containing list of items

Tags: python

I am new to programming and to python, currently using python3 via annoconda/jupyter. My input (test_Set) is list of quality score codes from a fastq file. The loop converts the quality score codes into quality scores. The following is the code I used

```
test_set=['.GA', '<AG', '#<<']
output1=[]
output2=[]
for i in test_set:
    s=i
    for j in range(len(s)):
        qs=ord(s[j])-33
        output1.append(qs)
    output2.append(output1)
```

The outputs i have are:

```
 output1: [13, 38, 32, 27, 32, 38, 2, 27, 27]
 output2: [[13, 38, 32, 27, 32, 38, 2, 27, 27],
          [13, 38, 32, 27, 32, 38, 2, 27, 27],
          [13, 38, 32, 27, 32, 38, 2, 27, 27]]
```

But the output i am trying to achieve is :

```
desired_output: [[13, 38, 32], [27, 32, 38], [2, 27, 27]]
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong with my loops and how to change them to achieve the desired output.
Thank you and appreciate any help, including resources to understand for and while loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right. You only need to "reset" `output1` in every pass of the for loop.

Here's a simplified version that does what you want:

```
test_set = ['.GA', '<AG', '#<<']
output2 = []

for s in test_set:
    output1 = [ord(c)-33 for c in s]
    output2.append(output1)
```

Because the string `s` is itself an iterable, you don't need to use the `len(range(s))` to index into it. Technically, you could do it in a one-liner, if you find it understandable-enough:

```
[[ord(c)-33 for c in s] for s in test_set]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_set=['.GA', '<AG', '#<<']
output=[]
for i in test_set:
    aux = []
    for j in range(len(i)):
        qs=ord(s[j])-33
        aux.append(qs)
    output.append(aux)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, the script only works for last three values of j. But i got this, thanks

Comment: glad I helped!!